# Append results in ul tag using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This code appends 1 or more `li` in `ul`, but every time, I run the code,  it continues appending.
I want to replace the appended data first time by new data. I tried using `.empty`, but if the data has more than 1 `li` tag, it returns only the last `li` as it clears the first iteration.

```
function addCourse(){
                    $.post("addCourse", function(result){
                    var response = $.parseJSON(result);
                          $.each( response, function( i, val ) {
                                var day = JSON.stringify(val.day).replace(/\"/g, "");
                                var hour = JSON.stringify(val.hour).replace(/\"/g, "");
                                var date = day+"_"+hour;
                            $("#div1").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' href=#"+date+">"+date+"</a></li>");
                           });
                });
            }
```

HTML code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="div1" role="tablist" >
      <li class="active" id="home">
          <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Home" >Home</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to use `.empty`, but probably in the wrong place. Try to use it before the `$.each`, e.g:

```
function addCourse() {
  $.post("addCourse", function(result) {
    var response = $.parseJSON(result);
    $("#div1").empty();
    $.each(response, function(i, val) {
      var day = JSON.stringify(val.day).replace(/\"/g, "");
      var hour = JSON.stringify(val.hour).replace(/\"/g, "");
      var date = day + "_" + hour;
      $("#div1").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' href=#" + date + ">" + date + "</a></li>");
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: it will remove this too 
<li class="active" id="home"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Home">Home</a> 
</li>

Comment: Instead of `$("div1").empty()`, you can do `$("div1").children().not('#home').remove()`

Comment: @HatemTito if my answer was useful for you, please mark it as the accepted one by clicking on the `V` right below the upvote/downvote arrows :)

Answer (score 0):

try use .html()

```
$("#div1").html("<li><a data-toggle='tab' href=#"+date+">"+date+"</a></li>");
```

or `$("#div1").html('');` and then `$("#div1").append('...');`